# Unexpected behavior in sockets in nodejs (double connections,

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twitter, socket.io

PROBLEM:
So I have a reactjs application that I created with npx create-react-app.

I also have a server running on my machine on port 8174(no significance just random). On this server I have some socket.io action going on.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('client connected')
}
```

Something weird which isn't really the problem, but may be related is that when I connect to the server it always runs twice. It will give me the "client connected" output twice in the server console.

The real problem is that I cannot figure out how to get this data into an array on the actual react application.

Here is the code in question:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'
import TweetCard from './TweetCard'





export default function TweetList() {
    const [tweetItems, setTweetItems] = useState([])
    const [socket] = useState(() => socketIOClient('http://localhost:8174/', {reconnection: true, forceNew: false}))
    var items = []

    const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
    }

    const streamTweets = async () => {
        socket.on('tweets', async data => {

       
            await sleep(1000)
            items = [...tweetItems, data]
            items = items.reverse()


            // items = items.filter(d => {return d.user != data.user})
            var count = 15

            items = items.filter(function(d) {
                if(count != 0){
                    count--
                    return true
                } 
                return false
            })
            console.log(items)
            setTweetItems(items)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        
        socket.once('connect', () => {
            console.log("Socket has successfully connected to server")
        })

        streamTweets()

        


        return () => {
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                socket.off("tweets");
                socket.removeAllListeners("tweets")
                console.log("Socket Disconnected")
            })
        }

    }, [])

    return (
        <div style={{ height: "300rem", scrollY: "auto", overflowY: "auto"}} >
            {tweetItems.map(tweet => {
                return <TweetCard tweet={tweet}/>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

THINGS I'VE TRIED:

- On the server level I did a io.once instead of io.on. This fixed the issue of the client connecting twice or a crazy number of times like 5 in one second. It predictively only connected once. The problem with this however is if I refresh the page on the app it disconnects forever and I couldn't figure out how to make it reconnect even though it was saying it was reconnecting. I will post the server code on how it is connecting below, but basically it would output ('resuming stream') when it was infact not resuming the stream.
- At first I just messed with the state directly (tweetItems). I basically make an array called `newArr = [...tweetItems, data]`. Then I set the state below it like `setTweetItems(newArr)`. This however just updated index 0 every single time it set the state. So it would always be an array of one single item. It would update the next tweet though.
- Tried using the bearer token instead of using require('twitter') package and tried implementing it in the 'twitter docs way of streaming' I can insert that link if needed. The code is outdated and incorrect though as I came to find out. I literally just forked the entire project at one point and put in my token. It did not work. They also use body parser still so its a strong sign that it is outdated
- Tried making a regular array without the state called `items =[]` this worked for a little bit , and I am not sure what I changed, but it eventually started to copy like 2 or 3 of the same item. like index 0 - 2 would all be the same twee 3 - 4 would all be the same tweet and so on.
- Also when I performed a "reverse()" on this items array it would give me a fatal error telling me that items = [...items, data] can't be set. This was odd because the code to reverse items was below this but the error was saying that items can't be set I am assuming it was doing something then after it "reversed" it went to set the items again and was null. I used `items = items.reverse()` this is what caused the error
- Tried making the streaming of the tweets async in the react(did nothing)
- Tried slowing down each setState by 1 second(did nothing)
- I have tried many more things, but hopefully this will give you an idea of the issue that I am having. Any help or tutorials on sockets would be awesome.

Here is the code that connects to the twitter API:

```
const Twitter = require('twitter')



module.exports = (app, io) => {
    var client = new Twitter({
        consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
        consumer_secret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
        access_token_key: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
        access_token_secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
    });

    let timeout = 0

    let socketConnection;
    let twitterStream;


    app.locals.searchTerm = 'giveaway'
    app.locals.showRetweets = false;

    //twitter stream
    const streamtweets = () => {
        console.log("Resuming stream for: " + app.locals.searchTerm)
        client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: app.locals.searchTerm, tweet_mode: 'extended', language: 'en'}, (streamData) => {
            streamData.on('data', (data) => {
                sendMessage(data)
             });

             streamData.on('error', (error) => {
                 console.log(error)
             })

             twitterStream = streamData
        })
    }

    const sleep = async (delay) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), delay));
    };


    //twitter stream
    io.on('connection', socket => {
        console.log(socket.id)
        socketConnection = socket;
        streamtweets();
        socket.on("connection", () => console.log("Client has connected to the server"))
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            console.log("Client has disconnected to the server")
            // twitterStream.destroy()
            // socket.off()

            // reconnect(twitterStream, socket)
        })
    })

    const reconnect = async (stream, socket) => {
        timeout++;
        stream.destroy()
        await sleep(2 ** timeout * 1000);
        // streamTweets(socket, token);
        streamtweets()
    };


    /**
     * Sets search term for twitter stream.
     */
    app.post('/setSearchTerm', (req, res) => {
        let term = req.body.term;
        app.locals.searchTerm = term;
        twitterStream.destroy();
        streamtweets();
    });


    const sendMessage = (data) => {
        if(data.text.includes('RT')){
            return;
        }
        socketConnection.emit("tweets", data)
    }
    
    
 
}
```

Comment: Don't use `var`; use `let`. Variable scoping is different and probably not what you expect.

Comment: do you mean var Items = []? @rveerd

Comment: Everywhere. Never use `var`. Only use `let` or `const`.

Comment: Jeebus I think I fixed it @rveerd I changed everything to a let or const and I also I created the socket in useEffect instead of including it in useState. So far I have been able to get rid of duplicate sockets which is nice. now on to test the array.